# html, body and divs with height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of content that stretched below the bottom of the screen. At the top of the page I have a div containing a "hero image". The div fills the height of the screen. I have acheived this by setting:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
.hero_div { height: 100%; }
```

But I don't understand why this works.

If I remove the height 100% from the body, the height is 3978 pixels (the height of the entire page/content). But with height 100% the height of the body is just 653 pixels (the height of the screen), but the content below this 653px is still displayed.

Surely body with height 100% should be the height of all the content/page within the body tag (in this case 3978px)?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Comment: If you add `min-height: 100%`, then the body will increase with the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely body with height 100% should be the height of all the content/page within the body tag

No. The `height: 100%` means "100% of the height of the element's content" not "100% of the height of the element's content".

The container for the HTML element is (effectively) the viewport.

> but the content below this 653px is still displayed.

The default value for `overflow` is not `hidden`.

Comment: This is going off beam, but if I set html, body, hero_div { height: 100% } then I have a second div (a drop down menu) with position absolute is there a way to get it to cover the height of the entire page? At the moment this second div with height 100% is the same height as the body = the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way:

If you  limit `html` and `body` to 100% height, its *content* will be scrolled, i.e. the *content* of 'body'.

If you don't put a height on 'body', `body` will have the full height of its content and will be scrolled inside `HTML`